# How can I make WebAudio.param work in Elm?

Tags: web-audio-api, elm

I'm just getting started with WebAudio in Elm, using hayleigh-dot-dev/elm-web-audio/1.1.1. I got the setup right, have sound, and things seems to work as intended. However, when I started using WebAudio.param to try out simple FM and AM, it doesn't connect, even when I copy the example code from the documentation.

Here is some minimal code, trying to get the FM from the example pages running:

```
port module Main exposing (main)

import Browser
import Html exposing (Html, div, text)
import Html.Attributes as HA
import Html.Events exposing (onClick)
import Json.Encode
import WebAudio
import WebAudio.Property


port toWebAudio : Json.Encode.Value -> Cmd msg


main : Program () Model Msg
main =
    Browser.element
        { init = init
        , update = update
        , view = view
        , subscriptions = \_ -> Sub.none
        }


init : () -> ( Model, Cmd msg )
init _ =
    ( (), Cmd.none )


type alias Model =
    ()


type Msg
    = StartAudio


update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
        StartAudio ->
            ( model
            , audio
                |> Json.Encode.list WebAudio.encode
                |> toWebAudio
            )


view : Model -> Html Msg
view _ =
    div
        [ HA.style "width" "400px"
        , HA.style "height" "400px"
        , HA.style "background-color" "#fae"
        , onClick StartAudio
        ]
        [ text <| "Click me to start audio" ]


audio : List WebAudio.Node
audio =
    [ WebAudio.oscillator
        [ WebAudio.Property.frequency 5 ]
        -- Connect to the "frequency" parameter of the "carrier" node
        [ WebAudio.param "carrier" "frequency" ]
    , WebAudio.keyed "carrier" <|
        WebAudio.oscillator []
            [ WebAudio.dac ]
    ]
```

And this is how it is connected in index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Elm web audio</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script> 

</head>

<body>
    <div id="myapp"></div>
</body>

<script type="module">
    import VirtualAudioContext from './elm-web-audio.js'

    const ctx = new AudioContext()
    const virtualCtx = new VirtualAudioContext(ctx)

    const app = Elm.Main.init({
        node: document.getElementById('myapp'),
        flags: 43
    })

    app.ports.toWebAudio.subscribe((nodes) => {
        virtualCtx.update(nodes)
    })

</script> 
</html>
```

I was expecting to hear some FM, but I only get a pure tone.

By the way, when getting started it was not clear to me which Elm-package to use, as there in addition to hayleigh-dot-dev/elm-web-audio/1.1.1 also appears the pd-andy/elm-web-audio/2.3.0. After some digging, it seems like they may be written by the same person, and that the latter package is deprecated; at least I got a 404 when trying to install it using "elm install pd-andy/elm-web-audio".